# Xpath: select div with grandchildren containing text

Tags: selenium, xpath

How do you write the xpath to select the div with class tableRow that contains a nested div with the title `apple` as well as a nested span with the text `3.14`?

```
<div class='tableRow'>
  <div class='tableCell'>
    <div class='container' title='apple'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='tableCell'>
    <span class='showSpan'>3.14</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To select an item anywhere in sub-tree with root at previously found node use `.//item`. And to get attribute use such syntax `@attribute`

```
//div[.//div[@title='apple'] and .//span[.='3.14']]
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include some explanation of what is going on so that OP and future readers will be able to understand what it's doing and why this works. If we don't educate readers how to create this themselves, they will be back with another question the next time they run into a similar scenario. [Teach a man to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) and all...

Comment: Thanks! It looks like you use `.//` to get into the div at any level.

Comment: @user9503053. Yes. I've updated the answer